# How to set permanent ipv4 for tap local bridge softether in centos 6

Tags: vpn, centos6, tap

I need help, i'm not familiar with linux network,

I use VPS centos 6.7 to create vpn server with softether + tap local bridge.
but this tap doesn't have default ipv4 address. So I must manually run this command to set this ip :

```
ifconfig tap_vpnlocal 192.168.30.1
```

Bbut after vps reboot, or unknown caused, It's reset without ipv4 like this:

```
tap_vpnlocal Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:AC:AF:6C:ED:33
      inet6 addr: fe80::2ac:afff:fe6c:ed33/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:225 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:1014 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:500
      RX bytes:15126 (14.7 KiB)  TX bytes:55896 (54.5 KiB)
```

I try to create this file /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-tap_vpnlocal
but doesn't work :

```
DEVICE=tap_vpnlocal
IPADDR=192.168.30.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=192.168.30.255
```

How to set it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

this closed,

i fix this with :

```
yum install tunctl
ifup tap_vpnlocal
```

copy this to vi /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-tap_vpnlocal

```
DEVICE=tap_vpnlocal
TYPE=Tap
ONBOOT=yes
STP=no
IPADDR=192.168.30.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
BROADCAST=192.168.30.255
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
BOOTPROTO=static
```

after reboot, the ip is automatic set,
if i set TYPE=Bridge, its failed